# Windows 10 Pro 20H2 - Code 43 on Intel HD and Nvidia GeForce

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have Dell Vostro 270 desktop PC.

I reinstalled Windows 10 Pro that was on it, using latest version available via Microsoft's Media Creation Tool.

After installing and running all updates both GPUs in the system are showing disabled in Device Manager with code 43. Same thing happens with both Windows Update and Dell SupportAssist software. I didn't install anything else.

before that there was no issue with those devices, but then PC ran older windows 10 build.

PC is quite old but still packs some punch, so I'd like to reuse it: i5-3470, 8GB ram, it has internal WiFi and 1TB hdd, so there is a lot of utility in it.

Provided I'll enable the GPUs. I think it has to do with W10 being the newest version, that somehow interferes with drivers.

Comment: This error occurs when your graphics device driver has notified Windows that the device isn’t working properly. This may mean that the device has a hardware problem, or that the driver or driver software is failing. I'm afraid that you may try to download the latest video card driver to install or roll back the system version to match the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing and just following some leads I found what was the issue. In retrospective this is obvious, but it took several hourw of solid and completely unnecessary work.

The GeForce 210 that is in the box is apparently not original part of the computer - when it was loaded with NVidia, it would be GF GT640 most likely (Dell had it's own GDDR5 model that was rated for 75W PCI-E power only and I worked with Vostro 270 such equipped), and most definitely not GF210.

It's apparently malfunctioning so it is properly detected but then it continues to disrupt whole PC. All started working well when I disabled it.

Case solved. Thanks to all who contributed.